# Viewing Manifolds as Embedded in Euclidean Space

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, mobius-band

In learning differential topology I've been exposed with two methods of defining and working with manifolds: The more concrete but initially less general approach of Guillemin and Pollack, where all manifolds sit inside an ambient Euclidean space; and the more abstract approach of most other books, like Lee's ISM, where manifolds are defined intrinsically via charts and atlases. One benefit of the second approach is that one can define a manifold by gluing (e.g. the Mobius strip or Klein bottle) without worrying if the prescribed gluing is possible in some Euclidean space.

But certain exercises in Guillemin and Pollack do seem to define manifolds by gluing (Exercise 1.6 in Chapter 2 does this with the Mobius strip). I don't see how this procedure can be rigorous unless the more abstract chart-atlas definition is used, so I wanted to know how Guillemin and Pollack expect their readers to formalize this construction if they have not been exposed to charts and atlases. For example, the reader is at one point asked to build the Mobius strip as a manifold with boundary by gluing opposite ends of a square together. Is it possible to do this rigorously when we're working with the definition that all manifolds must sit inside Euclidean space?

Comment: Well the example you mention can be done rigorously in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @AdamMartens How would that be done?

Comment: You can parametrize the unit disc in such a way that the image is the Möbius strip

Comment: @AdamMartens So this would involve showing that the image of the map is homeomorphic to the Mobius strip? Certainly we can't prove diffeomorphism because the Mobius strip hasn't even been given as a manifold yet

Comment: There is an important theorem, called Whitney's embedding theorem, that states that given any abstractly defined manifold $M^n$, there exists an embedding $M\rightarrow \mathbb R^{2n}$. This means that you can always assume that your manifold is a submanifold of euclidean space. Of course you need to check, that whatever you are doing, does not depend on the embedding. I don't have the book in front of me, but I think G&P are probably sloppy here.

Comment: @ThomasRot I'm aware of the Whitney embedding theorem, my question was more that if we pretend that we've never seen the definition of an abstract manifold and are only familiar with the G&P definition, is it possible to formalize the construction of a manifold by gluing?